# How can I count the time spent in a day in establishing connections between two servers?

Tags: windows, connection

I have two servers, one is a SQL Server and the other one is a webserver with IIS installed.

I'd need to find a -weird, admittedly- information: how much time the webserver spend during a day, in total, in establishing connections to the SQL Server?

---

To give things a little more context...

The issue is that our current web application is so badly designed that it executes thousands of queries for even the simplest task: the user clicks a button and, voila', 3 minutes and 70k calls later the result is given. This is clearly bad, and I want the company to address it, but I want to get some numbers too.

What I want to extract here is how much total time is spent daily in the connection process -both connection and disconnection-, with the time spent waiting for the answer itself not included.

Let's say that the communication goes this way:

1. The webserver open the connection
2. The webserver send the request to the DB server
3. The DB server is doing its stuff, while the webserver is waiting for result
4. The DB server sends back the results
5. The connection get closed.

What I'd want is the total of 1+2+5, lag included, for every communications between the two servers, for an entire day. Possible? Impossible?

Comment: *"how much total time is spent daily in the connection process -both connection and disconnection"* - that doesn't seem to be a very useful metric.  Usually logging/graphing the number of connections is already enough to make a solid argument to implement connection pooling in an application.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to calculate how much time is spent executing the queries on the database server? How is knowing how much time is spent NOT executing queries on the database server helpful?

Answer (score 1):

There are other network-related performances that you won't be appreciating AFTER the connection has established. Most notably, the effect of round-trip delay, but also TCP slow-start.

You should be able to avoid most of the slow-start and connection overhead by using a connection pool (I could be wrong... implementation details and all), but the biggest problem will your performance will be scale very poorly the further you get from the server.

70k requests is a big number. Ping a machine very close to you on the network. Now ping a machine in a different part of the network. Let's say that's like the difference between a small SoHO network and a large network, where the client application is for example on a user's desktop, and the database in housed in a database server in a datacentre.

Now how many TCP round-trips are actually required on average for one of these requests. Now work and how many round-trips, and thus the total time spent in waiting for round-trips.

This is a good reason why a client-side application and database are a bad idea; you want an application-server component that is close to the database, so the business logic and the database are always close together.